# How to give a call to more than two Get method using mvc4 web api controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm working on `mvc4 web api` project.

I have created a new controller `GroupValuesController` and i have following methods

```
public GroupViewModel Get()
public List<GroupModel> Get(Guid Id)
public List<GroupModel> GetDetails(Guid Id)
```

First two methods are working fine I'm calling them from a `group.cshtml view` like following

```
            $.getJSON(
                "api/groupvalues",
                function (data) {
```

and

```
$.getJSON(
                "api/groupvalues/" + id,
                function (data) {
```

For third controller method `public List<GroupModel> GetDetails(Guid Id)` i'm executing that from `Details.cshtml view` like following but it is not working.
i'm mismatching some calling ?

```
 function getGroupDataById(id, ctrl) {
        $.getJSON(
                "api/groupvalues/GetDetails/" + id,
                function (data) {
```

Is this related with Route?

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Comment: Do you get 404, 200, or 500 error responses when you make the call that is not working?

Comment: @Josh yes getting `404 error`

Comment: Url difference i found is http://localhost:14514/api/groupvalues/Get/2c78a982-4cf4-496b-945b-713c965af6ab‌​ --working http://localhost:14514/Group/Detail/api/groupvalues/GetDetails/98760a89-1ab2-42‌​a7-a731-84db5ad30c12 --- not working –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really doesn't matter what you write after Get, it is going to call the first one with same arguments. Web API don't rely on name rather they rely on HTTP verbs.

Comment: Url difference i found is 
`http://localhost:14514/api/groupvalues/Get/2c78a982-4cf4-496b-945b-713c965af6ab`   --working


`http://localhost:14514/Group/Detail/api/groupvalues/GetDetails/98760a89-1ab2-42a7-a731-84db5ad30c12`   --- not working

Answer (score 2):

Per the link below, in order to target that action method the way you have, you need to change your routing:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/624180/Routing-Basics-in-ASP-NET-Web-API

Comment: True But still call is not going from Detail.cshtml 
It is going good for 1st two methods those are from Group.cshtml 
:(
Getting getting 404 error for 3rd method when called from Detail.cshtml

Comment: i think it is finding method in detail it self see the URL error is 400
`http://localhost:14514/Group/Detail/api/groupvalues/GetDetails/af0eaed2-c338-4880-9bf5-40473462e5b3`

Comment: I did this once. I remember i ended up adding same as the route suggested here, and kept also the default route but as second route.